How to do a list for move towards(enemy)
I have a script for enemy and i and like to make a list of points, where enemy can go.
i tryed make it with serialize field construct, but clones(prefabs) spawn without a transform positions
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform endPoint;
    public int health;
    public float speed;
    private float progress;

    private void Start()
    {
        endPoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("EndPos").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, endPoint.position, progress * Time.deltaTime);
        progress = speed;
    }
}


how do you mean they spawn with out a transform position?  - nothing here shows how you spawn them.  Second, if the tag EndPos is not found, it wont set that at start.. so.. this gives you places to look
